# multiple elements with toggle function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of divs in my webpage and I want the target divs to toggle when the trigger divs are clicked.

```
<div class="trigger">...</div>
<div class="target">...</div>
```

I know the jQuery function to achieve this with one set of divs but is there any way to bind a trigger-div to a target-div so each trigger-div triggers the right div to toggle?

Comment: are the trigger and target elements next to each other always?

Comment: @NarenMurali yes they are

Comment: Have you researched this yourself? 5 minutes checking the docs would give you your answer. http://api.jquery.com/click, http://api.jquery.com/next, http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 0):

For a **strictly semantic HTML5**, you could use the HTML5 `<details>` tag.
The `<details>` tag can be used to create an interactive widget that the user can open and close. Any sort of content can be put inside the `<details>` tag.

```
 <details>
      <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
      <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
 </details>
```

There are many JavaScript / CSS approaches, but I would suggest using the recommended tags whenever possible. Just keep in mind that, for now, the trigger event do not work on IE -- but it shows the full content without errors.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example, I attach a click event to the class trigger, then I use `this` which is basically the clicked element, and access the adjacent element with next() and then add a class.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/zncv6t2f/2/)

Comment: thank you very much. this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @fatso88 You're welcome, try to include your coding attempt when posting the question next time :)